# Excel subtracting macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in column A and values in column B, I want to have a subtraction of these two in column C, so it goes `C1=B1-A1, C2=B2-A2`, etc.
I still cant code in VBA so I tried using macros manually, but the problem is I have got a lot of lists in this sheet and each of them has a different number of rows, so I ended up with more calculations on specific  list than I needed. How to do subtractions only for the number of rows in specific list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub forEachWs()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            lastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            ws.Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Formula = "=B1-A1"
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

you dont Need macros or anything for this

just write the Formular you expext in C1 and then click on the small black box and in the right Corner

[image: screenshot] 

and drag it down.

this will give you for `C2 = A2+B2` for `C3 A3+B3` ... etc.

Comment: Thank you, I know that this is possible, but I have about 30 lists each on about 20 sheets and I need to do it quickly just like ctrl+ smth, it takes less time, thats why I am looking for macro solution.

Comment: All lists of the same size (number of rows)?

Comment: @FDavidov No actually, as I wrote, each list has a different number of rows and that applies for each sheets as well

Comment: I don't quite see any simple solution that would not require some vba. Sorry.

Comment: @FDavidov Thats what  I thought, but would you be able to post a solution containing VBA? I have basic programming experience, so I might understand a bit of it, but for this one-time use it shouldnt matter anyway.

Comment: I can give you guidelines only. Sorry but not much free time to write code.

Comment: That's one beautiful hand drawn circle.  The sharp corners really nailed it for me ;)

Comment: @RGA yeah i know i should go to the graphic designer Exchange site ^^